# Is there an Eclipse C# Highlight, Code Completion plugin

Tags: c#, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting, code-completion

I need an Eclipse 3 plugin for C# syntax highlight and hopefully code completion.

I am running both Mac and Windows versions of Eclipse.

I have evaluated "Improve C#" but it seems to be not working.

Comment: I think most people who want to develop C# use Visual Studio C# Express, SharpDevelop, or MonoDevelop. All of which are free. I don't think there is much effort for a C# plugin for Eclipse anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [Emonic](http://emonic.sourceforge.net/). It is an Eclipse plug-in which allows you to build C# programs with Mono or Microsoft .NET.