# Is there a way to get syntax coloring in eclipse for .vb and .cs files?

Tags: c#, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an Eclipse C# Highlight, Code Completion plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952973/is-there-an-eclipse-c-sharp-highlight-code-completion-plugin)
>   [Eclipse IDE, C# and VB.Net plugins that supports .Net Framework4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299872/eclipse-ide-c-sharp-and-vb-net-plugins-that-supports-net-framework4-0)

I'm so addicted to eclipse that I use it for almost everything. Is there a plugin that would allow me to have syntax coloring in Eclipse for dotnet .vb and .cs files ? I'm not trying to build the projects or execute anything. Just to view the code with syntax coloring.

Comment: So, you will not even try Visual Studio (call me a pusher, if you will...)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444625/c-sharp-plugin-for-eclipse

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952973/is-there-an-eclipse-c-sharp-highlight-code-completion-plugin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145484/looking-for-up-to-date-eclipse-plugin-for-c-sharp

Comment: I would recommend you use SharpDevelop if you feel like building .NET projects with open-source IDE in the future or now.

Comment: @Oded I use Visual Studio to develop. I just find that the find resource and text search, replace and navigate capabilities are poor in visual studio... I use it only to write the code, not to explore.

Comment: @all thanks, sorry for not finding the dupplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look [Emonic](http://emonic.sourceforge.net/) plugin.

> Emonic stands for Eclipse Mono Integration. It is an Eclipse plug-in
>   which allows you to build C# programs with Mono or Microsoft .NET.

[image]

Comment: Why does the screenshot look quite... old?

Comment: Could be resolution problem, [look at the originale](http://emonic.sourceforge.net/html/CSharpEditorWithCompletion.html)

Comment: @AlvinWong look at the icon in the top left corner => this man has a beard ;=) http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/